# Unity Hub не работает кнопка create

Tags: unity-hub

[image: *]

Именно интересует кнопка *create
она просто серая и... я не знаю что с этим делать. я попробовал переустановить хаб, перезагрузил пк, установил новую версию редактора. помогите люди добрые...

Comment: Может, у вас уже существует проект с таким названием и поэтому нельзя создать новый?